# Parameter passing in C

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int param = *argv[1];
    printf("Parameter = %d\n",param);   
}
```

I run it ./myProgram 5 and I expect 5 as an output. What I get is 53 for some reason.

Comment: Each member of argv is a string, you treat it as if it were an integer.  If you want the integer you have to extract it using eg atoi.

Comment: Hint: 53 = '5' in ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the declaration, argv is an array of char pointers. This means that your main function is not being passed the numerical value 5, but the (probably ASCII- or UTF8-) encoded string value "5". If you look at [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com), you will see that the character "5" is encoded as the numerical value 53 in ASCII. You can also see that the letter "a" is encoded as number 97, so running `./myProgram a` should output `Parameter = 97`.

To get the numerical value of an ASCII-encoded string you can use atoi(), e.g. write

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int param = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Parameter = %d\n",param);   
}
```

Comment: atoi() doesn't work. "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: The atoi() function works on a char pointer, so make sure you remove the asterisk from `*argv[1]`.

Comment: yeah atoi() works now.

Comment: In case `0` shall be a possible value to be converted `atoi()` cannot be used as it returns `0` on error also. `strtol()` is the function of choice, to also cover `0`. @kulan

Answer (score 1):

C does not implcitily convert an array's content to any type.

To try to convert a `0`-terminated `char`-array (a C "string") to an `int` consider using `strtol()`.